# TTSearchTextFieldDelegate not calling textField:didSelectObject:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

I have an implementation of a `TTSearchTextFieldDelegate` in a `TTTableViewController`.

My header looks like this:

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>

@protocol SearchTestControllerDelegate;
@class MockDataSource;

@interface SearchTestController : TTTableViewController <TTSearchTextFieldDelegate> {
    id<SearchTestControllerDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<SearchTestControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol SearchTestControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)searchTestController:(SearchTestController*)controller didSelectObject:(id)object;

@end
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
#import "SearchTestController.h"
#import "MockDataSource.h"

@implementation SearchTestController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// NSObject

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        _delegate = nil;

        self.title = @"Search Test";
        self.dataSource = [[[MockDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// UIViewController

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    TTTableViewController* searchController = [[[TTTableViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    searchController.dataSource = [[[MockSearchDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.searchViewController = searchController;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TTTableViewController

- (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    [_delegate searchTestController:self didSelectObject:object];
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TTSearchTextFieldDelegate

- (void)textField:(TTSearchTextField*)textField didSelectObject:(id)object {
    [_delegate searchTestController:self didSelectObject:object];
}

@end
```

The method `- (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;` is getting called and works perfectly. It is for when a cell in the `TTTableView` has been selected.

However the method `- (void)textField:(TTSearchTextField*)textField didSelectObject:(id)object` is never getting called. This method should be called when I select a cell in the `TTTableView` after I have searched for something.

What am I doing wrong? This is basically the example for `TTCatalog` from here: https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples/TTCatalog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` and in `-(void)loadView:` I set `_searchController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;`

Then the only thing left was to implement this method:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TTTableImageItemCell *cell = (TTTableImageItemCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    TTTableImageItem *object = [cell object];
    [_delegate searchTestController:self didSelectObject:object];
}
```